# Partial Logout while implementing Single Logout Profile

Tags: java, logout, saml-2.0

I have two SPs (Service Providers) and I am using Ping as IdP. While implementing Single Logout Profile through SAML, I am getting the response back from IdP with status `PartialLogout`.

So main SP sends a `LogoutRequest` to Ping, Ping sends a `LogoutRequest` to participating SP, participating SP terminates session and sends a `LogoutResponse` to Ping, Ping sends a `LogoutResponse` to main SP. This LogoutResponse contains the status as PartialLogout, I am not sure what I am missing. I checked the log for Ping server and it says "`Signature Required`"  while using redirect binding from participating SP to IdP while sending `LogoutResponse`.

I am using the same certificate to sign the `LogoutResponse`(participating SP to IdP) which I used to sign `LogoutRequest` (main SP to IdP). Not sure what I am missing in this implementation. Does anybody have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this through help from Ping. The signature should be created using `SAMLResponse=XXXXX&RelayState=YYYYY&SigAlg=ZZZZ` and then used as a value for `signature` parameter. This is specially if `HTTP-REDIRECT` binding used. In case of `POST` binding, this is not required.